# missing menu bar in texstudio 2.10.8 on linux mint 17.3

Tags: linux-mint

I normally use the most recent version of TexStudio with my Linux Mint system by downloading the source tarball and compiling it in my machine. Recently I upgraded Mint to 17.3 and TexStudio to 2.10.8 at the same time. 
However, when I installed TexStudio, the menu bar was not there anymore, I uninstalled and reinstalled the stable version 2.6.6, everything was fine, but upgrading it to 2.10.8 again, menu was lost.

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

it worked fine for me, taking the **xUbuntu 14.04** package. Linux Mint 17.3 is based on that version of Ubuntu. Its better to use the pre-build package